# Alpha - Time Series vs Cross Section Approach

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing, capm, fama-french

I am currently reading Cochranes book on asset pricing. However, I get confused about one thing. He says that one could test a factor model (I will use the CAPM, just as he does), via a time series approach (a) and a cross section approach (b) (and the Fama McBeth procedure which I do not want to discuss here, though).

(a) Let $t$ denote the period, then estimate $R_t = \alpha + \beta f_t + \epsilon_t$ for every asset $i$. The respective factor model, in this case the CAPM, implies that each $\alpha$ should be zero. One can test for this by use of certain tests.

(b) Take the $\beta$ of each asset $i$ from (a). Then estimate $E_T(R_i)= \beta_i \lambda + \alpha_i$. He says that in this case $\alpha_i$ denotes the cross sectional regression residuals and the pricing errors.

My questions are: Does the $\alpha$ in (a) equal the $\alpha$ in (b), at least from a theoretical perspective, i.e. intercept in (a) is equal to the residual in (b)? How do the $\alpha$ values relate to Jensens Alpha? From my understanding, Jensens Alpha is the difference between expected return and the predicted return. This clearly corresponds to the residual in (b), i.e. the $\alpha$ in (b). If this connection is in fact true, do factor models predict Jensens Alpha to be zero by construction?